# Second-order linear elliptic PDE on $S^2\times S^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations, linear-pde

I'm facing the problem of proving existence/non-existence of a (unique and or weak) non-trivial solution to the following PDE on the Riemannian manifold ($S^2\times S^2$, $g$) with $g$ smooth (but not quite the round) metric tensor:

$$Pu=0,\quad P=\Delta+A:C^\infty(S^2\times S^2)\rightarrow C^\infty(S^2\times S^2)$$

with $u$ real-valued, $\Delta=\ast\mathrm{d}\ast\mathrm{d}$ the Laplacian and $A$ containing first- and zeroth-order terms with smooth non-constant coefficients.

Ellipticity is evident from the Laplacian, hence $P$ is Fredholm. Unfortunately, the index (which only depends on the principal symbol, i.e. $\sigma(\Delta)$) vanishes, so I can't use it to show existence of solutions. I also thought about proving things locally and then patching using partitions of unity but this doesn't seem to be working.

Although there is an abundance of literature about existence/regularity theory on $\mathbb{R}^n$ for second-order linear elliptic operators, the only reference I found that contains similar considerations are the notes by Melrose (and to the best of my very limited understanding, he does not talk about existence at all, only about regularity).

So I'd appreciate both, good references about the topic and concrete hints how to show that there does(n't) exist some $u$. Cheers!

Comment: Is A linear in $u , \nabla u$?

Comment: @ArcticChar $A$ is some first-order differential operator, giving rise to terms like e.g. $\langle\omega ,\mathrm{d}u\rangle$ and $\phi u$ with $\omega$ some 1-form and $\phi$ a function on $S^2\times S^2$, everything smooth.

Comment: The operator $P = \Delta +A$ is Fredholm and has a discrete spectrum $\lambda_1 \le \lambda _2 \le \cdots $. So $P u =0$ for a nonzero $u$ if and only if $0$ is a eigenvalue of $P$. I am not sure what's more can be said since your $A$ is very general.

Comment: @ArcticChar Right, the point would then basically be how to show that $0$ is an eigenvalue and what regularity properties such a $u$ will have. (I should mention that I'm usually doing stuff far away from functional analysis etc.)

Comment: @JDecou: The reason you don't see the existence question discussed much is that you can't really show existence in such a general setting. Think about the case where $Au = -\lambda u$. Then $Pu = \Delta(u) - \lambda u = 0$ has a solution iff $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $\Delta$ and in general, you can't determine the spectrum of $\Delta$, even in very nice situations. The only general thing you can deduce is what Arctic Char said. Also, by ellipticity, if you have a weak solution you will also have a smooth solution and, by linearity, if a non-zero solution exists, it won't be unique.

Comment: @levap Ok, I see. But, say, I pick a concrete form of $A$. Are there any estimates I can give on the spectrum (ideally like $0<\lambda_1\le\lambda_2\le\dots$ of course)?

Comment: Also, is being Fredholm enough to have a discrete spectrum? I thought $P$ would have to be (formally) self-adjoint as well (which $P$ in general is not).

Comment: @JDecou: In general, the eigenvalues will form an infinite discrete set with no finite accumulation point. This is not a consequence of the fact that $P$ is Fredholm (as a map between appropriate spaces) but follows from the fact that the resolvent is compact. See Renardy's Introduction to Partial Differential Equations, Theorem 9.21 for a version which is stated for domains in $\mathbb{R}^n$). If the operator is self-adjoint then the eigenvalues will be real and accumulate at $+\infinity$.

Comment: @levap Ok, thanks! So is there any lower bound on the spectrum for nice enough $P$?